# Как изменить значение jquey range в зависимости от значения select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть форма. Есть выпадающий список (select) и есть числовой отрезок (jquery range)(м2 и млн р) . Давайте обратим внимание на этот отрезок. Он сделан из jqueryui.com/slider/#range и имеет такой html код

```
<div class="slider-range"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
<input type="text" id="amount1" readonly>
```

Сами числовые значения этого отрезка берутся из js

```
$(function() {
    $( ".slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 10,
      max: 120,
      values: [ 40, 60 ],
      step: 2,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "м2");
        $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] + "м2");
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( + $( ".slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "м2")
     $( "#amount1" ).val( + $( ".slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + "м2")
  });
```

Задумка такая: Когда я меняю значение в пункте "что" на земельный участок, то js код в числовом отрезке отвечающий за площадь должен обрести другую форму. Поменяются значения min,max,values и step, а так же "м2" изменится на ар (сотка). Изменение через select можно реализовать с помощью https://api.jquery.com/change/ . Только я не совсем понимаю, как можно реализовать эту задумку. Так получилось, что я в js ноль... Помогите пожалуйста написать код.
[image: Сама форма]

Answer (score 1):

Такая проблема может возникнуть почти в любом языке программирования, не только JavaScript.
Вам всего-лишь нужно провести рефакторинг "extract variable" на строке "м2". Возможно, в меню вашей IDE есть такой пункт